# Correlated Query with more than one table SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I need to list some staff details who are registered for 2 or more courses using a sub query.
The staff_id in the staff table is linked to the course table, so s.staff_id = c.staff_id. But I'm really confused and don't know how to correct.

```
SELECT STAFF.STAFF_ID, STAFF.FIRST_NAME, STAFF.LAST_NAME, STAFF.TITLE, COURSE.ID 
FROM STAFF, COURSE C
WHERE STAFF.STAFF_ID = COURSE.STAFF_ID
AND (SELECT COURSE.COURSE_ID FROM COURSE 
GROUP BY STAFF.STAFF_ID
HAVING COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_ID) >=2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want staff that have more than one course, a `join` is not necessary -- implicit or explicit.  Here is a more direct approach:

```
select s.*
from staff s
where s.staff_id in (select c.staff_id
                     from course c
                     group by c.staff_id
                     having count(*) >= 2
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don’t need a correlated subquery. An aggregate JOIN query with a HAVING clause should do it, like :

```
SELECT
    S.STAFF_ID, 
    S.FIRST_NAME,
    S.LAST_NAME, 
    S.TITLE 
FROM 
    STAFF AS S
    INNER JOIN COURSE AS C
        ON S.STAFF_ID = C.STAFF_ID
GROUP BY
    S.STAFF_ID, 
    S.FIRST_NAME,
    S.LAST_NAME, 
    S.TITLE
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) >=2
;
```

This will retrieve all staff persons that have at least two courses.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to link your sub query back to your main query.  At the moment you are just looking for ANY staff member that has more than two courses in your sub query.  Try the below (untested).

For clarity especially when you are using sub queries it is a good idea to alias all of your tables.

```
SELECT S.STAFF_ID, S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.TITLE 
FROM STAFF S, COURSE C
WHERE S.STAFF_ID = C.STAFF_ID
AND (SELECT C1.COURSE_ID FROM COURSE c1
     where s.staff_id = c1.staff_id
     HAVING COUNT(C1.COURSE_ID) >=2)
```

The above assumes that you need to get some columns out of course as well, however at the moment you have none in your first select so the query could be further simplified to the below if you do not need anything from course.

```
SELECT S.STAFF_ID, S.FIRST_NAME, S.LAST_NAME, S.TITLE 
FROM STAFF S
where (SELECT C.COURSE_ID FROM COURSE c
     where s.staff_id = c.staff_id
     HAVING COUNT(C.COURSE_ID) >=2)
```

Comment: Ah I forgot I needed to select the course_id in the first part

Answer (score 0):

If you want only staff details or else can `join` if needed course details as well

```
      SELECT Staff.* from Staff s where   
        s.staff_id in 
     (Select 
     staff_id from
           (SELECT  COURSE_ID,STAFF_ID
           FROM COURSE 
            GROUP BY STAFF_ID
       HAVING COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_ID) >=2)
        );
```

or via join infact even in join you require a subquery reason being `group by` when grouping by s.staff_id the c.course_id values will become inconsistent and unsync with s.staff_id

```
           Select s.* ,c.COURSE_ID from staff s
            join course c
            on s.staff_id IN (Select c.staff_id group by 
               c.staff_id
             HAVING COUNT(*) >=2)
```